# Sortable jQuery UI list with buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, button, jquery-ui-sortable

Following the examples in the jQuery UI [demo](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) and [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/), I'm using this HTML:

```
<ul class="sort">
  <li>
    <button>A</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button>B</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button>C</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And this JS:

```
$(function () {
  $('.sort').sortable();
})
```

But as seen in [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/GA4Qs/338/), the buttons are not drag-able.

How can I make .sortable() work with buttons?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sortable provides a [`cancel` selector](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel) to prevent sorting on specified elements. The default value includes `<button>` elements, and your sort handles are buttons, so sorting is prevented:

> **cancel**
>   Type: Selector
>   Default: "input,textarea,button,select,option"
>   Prevents sorting if you start on elements matching the selector.

To solve this, set the `cancel` selector to an empty string:

```js
$('.sort').sortable({
  cancel: ''
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul class="sort">
  <li><button>A</button></li>
  <li><button>B</button></li>
  <li><button>C</button></li>
</ul>
```

[View on JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GA4Qs/340/)

---

Also, you can specify the draggable handles for `sortable()` by using the [`handle` option](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-handle):

```
$('.sort').sortable({handle:'button'});
```

But in your case, the entire content of each `<li>` element is a `<button>`, so you won't need to specify it.

Comment: Beat me to it!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: after almost 1 decade, this answer is still relevant 

Answer (score 3):

Ahhh, you know what?  jQuery UI prevents .sortable() from working on buttons by default, as stated in [the .cancel() section of the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel)!  Clearing this default allows the buttons to be sort-able like in [this updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/GA4Qs/339/).

The functional JS/jQuery looks like this:

```
$(function () {
  $('.sort').sortable({
    cancel: ''
  });
})
```